# What's the way to use cloneWithout with the Laravel query builder?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to use the `cloneWithout` method from the Laravel query builder but it has no effect.

**Sample:**

```php
use App\Models\Quote;

$query = Quote::query()->select(['id', 'status', 'supplier_id'])->orderBy('id');

$cloned = $query->cloneWithout(['orders']);

return [
  $query->toRawSql(),
  $cloned->toRawSql()
];
```

**Output:**

```json
[
    "select `id`, `status`, `supplier_id` from `quotes` order by `id` asc",
    "select `id`, `status`, `supplier_id` from `quotes` order by `id` asc",
]
```

**I was expecting to get the out put as:**

```json
[
    "select `id`, `status`, `supplier_id` from `quotes` order by `id` asc",
    "select `id`, `status`, `supplier_id` from `quotes`",
]
```

Comment: This is about loaded relations - this command unload loaded relations from clone, but not modify query.

Comment: @Maksim Check [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/3365194f659e9d17083fa715e09db65b6154c18f/tests/Database/DatabaseQueryBuilderTest.php#L5643) out. 
The test for this feature is the same as the question.

Comment: @AmooAti Wow, really, i’m confused with replicate. Good, good, new feature for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `cloneWithout` is not working on Eloquent Builders and only works on Query Builder.

**Solution 1:**
Using DB Facade:

```php
...
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

...

$query = DB::table('quotes')->select(['id', 'status', 'supplier_id'])->orderBy('id');

$cloned = $query->cloneWithout(['orders']);

return [
    $query->toSql(),
    $cloned->toSql()
];
```

If you insist on using the Quote model, You may want to consider trying these two options as well:
**Solution 2:**

Clone whole object using PHP's `clone` and then add `orderBy`.

```php
$query = Quote::query()->select(['id', 'status', 'supplier_id']);

$cloned = clone $query;

$query->orderBy('id');

return [
    $query->toSql(),
    $cloned->toSql()
];
```

**Solution 3 (Recommended):**

Convert your Eloquent Builder to Query Builder using `toBase`

```php
$query = Quote::query()->select(['id', 'status', 'supplier_id'])->orderBy('id')->toBase();

$cloned = $query->cloneWithout(['orders']);

return [
    $query->toSql(),
    $cloned->toSql()
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just chain your `$query` variable with Laravel's `toBase()` function and it will work.

like below

```
$cloned = $query->toBase()->cloneWithout(['orders']);
```

You can read more about [toBase()](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_toBase) here.